# WHY do I get an empty object when searching by element or xpath _____ HTMLSession, requests-html

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath, python-requests-html

I just want to verify the element exists somehow. Trying to print it so I can compare against a string or something.

Here is the problematic code.

```
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sony-PlayStation-5-Video-Game-Console/994712501')

r.html.render(timeout=20)# this call executes the js in the page

oos=r.html.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div')

print(oos)

#print returns []
```

I try to `print(oos.text)` and I get a callback error

> #'list' object has no attribute 'text'

also tried `print(oos.full_text)` same error

> 'list' object has no attribute 'full_text'

Seems like its a list? So I tried to iterate through it.

```
for i in oos:       
  print(i)
#Prints absolutely nothing!
```

Comment: Does your xpath work when you search by it in Chrome (or other browser's) dev tools? Are you sure it's right? It is so messy it would be easy to make a mistake there.

Comment: I just tried it. It works in developer tools. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried print(r.html)? I have run your code and it seems that I encounter a scraping-blocking page, so no surprise your xpath returns nothing.

Comment: I am changing my User-Id and a couple of other "header" settings. I tried some other sites and I was getting network codes in 400's without changing the header. I honestly don't know if that's required for this site or not but it was changed when I tried this. I can print(r.html) with this site. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the element doesn't exist. Based on an examination of print(html) I believe I am being redirected to a capthcha page.

Therefore I am going to assume that the [] is essentially an empty list and all code is more or less doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Based on my tests, you definitely are redirected to another page, apparently with sort of a captcha.